# Update dynamic data in service-worker.js

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, service-worker, chrome-gcm

I have the below data coming in form of array from a url.

```
[{"title":"hey hi","body":"hello","url":"https://simple-push-demo.appspot.com/","tag":"new"}]
```

**service-worker.js**
it has the above url in fetch()

```
 'use strict';

console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed new', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activatednew', event);
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    try{
  console.log('Push message', event);
  var ev = event;

  //sample
  return fetch("http://localhost/push-notifications-master/app/json.php").then(function(ev,response) {
    response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
    return response;
}).then(function(ev,j) {
    // Yay, `j` is a JavaScript object
    console.log("j", j);
 for(var i in j) {
    var _title = j[i].title;
    var _body = j[i].body;
    var _tag = j[i].tag;
     console.log("_body", _body);
    }
    ev.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification("push title", {
      body: _body,
      icon: 'images/icon.png',
      tag: _tag
    }));    
});

return Promise.all(response);

    }
    catch(e){console.log("e", e)}
});
```

I am trying to see the above array data coming from that particular url in `console.log("j",j);`. but it shows undefined. How can i get dymanic data in sw.js  Please Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your addEventListener('push' .... method, I think it might be better to wait for a response before parsing it.

Also, to be checked, but your php request should be in https (not checked by myself, but my request are on https).

Here how I do this :

```
event.waitUntil(
    fetch('YOUR PHP URL').then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);  
            throw new Error();  
        }
        // Examine the text in the response  
        return response.json().then(function(data) { 
            if (data.error || !data.notification) {
                console.error('The API returned an error.', data.error);  
                throw new Error();  
            }
            var title = data.notification[0].title;  
            var body = data.notification[0].body;  
            var icon = data.notification[0].icon;  
            var notificationTag = data.notification[0].tag;
            return self.registration.showNotification(title, {body: body,icon:icon, tag: notificationTag});
        });
    })
);
```

The json :

```
{"notification" : [{"title":"TITLE","body":"BODY","icon":"URL TO ICON","tag":"TAG"}]}
```

Hope it can be useful.

Comment: How to handle CORS error in this? I have used 'mode': 'no-cors' in fetch API, but it is returning 0 as http status code. Any help?